# Bootstrap Panel Refuses to Push Content Down When Opened

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am currently messing around with the Boostrap Panel class and have hit a roadblock. When I click to open the panel, the content beneath the panel does not get pushed down, but instead layers on top of the panel. I thought I might be able to use a z-index on the panel, but that didn't work. Ideally the panel should push content down, but overlaying above the content would be acceptable as well. Here's some stripped down code, tried using jsfiddle, but it was giving me a fit! Let me know if you need more info, thanks! (images at bottom)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <meta name="description" content="" />
    <meta name="author" content="" />
    <link rel="icon" href="assets/img/favicon.ico" />

    <title>UNCVRD</title>

    <!-- Bootstrap Core CSS -->

    <link href="assets/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />

    <!-- Font awesome icons -->
    <link href="assets/css/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

    <!-- Custom Css -->
    <link href="assets/css/custom.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Google Fonts -->
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Reem+Kufi" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="https://use.typekit.net/wvu7wqs.js"></script>
    <script>
        try {
            Typekit.load({
                async: true
            });
        } catch (e) {}

    </script>

    <!-- Ionicons -->
    <link href="http://code.ionicframework.com/ionicons/2.0.1/css/ionicons.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- HTML5 shiv and REspond.js IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->

    <!--[if lt IE9]>
    <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.2/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->

</head>


<div class="lyrics-container">
    <div class="panel-group">
        <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-heading">
                <h4 class="panel-title">
                              <a data-toggle="collapse" id="lyric-toggle" href="#collapse1"><i class="icon ion-chevron-down"></i>LYRICS</a>
                            </h4>
            </div>
            <div id="collapse1" class="panel-collapse collapse">
                <div class="panel-body">
                    Don't tell me this is over
                    <br> I'll carry you on my shoulder
                    <br> I'm marching on like a soldier
                    <br> Turn up the heat
                    <br> I get colder
                    <br> You see the trash as a treasure
                    <br> I'm getting closer than ever
                    <br> But there it blow,
                    <br> I got stronger
                    <br> Just need a little bit longer
                    <br> I'm the one but a sinner
                    <br> I'm finding to see it clearer
                    <br> So let me show you the winner
                    <br> That's how I pray for forgiveness
                    <br> No I ain't drowning, I'm boiling
                    <br> I'll left this world up alone
                    <br> I'll never be a quitter
                    <br> Even if it would kill me
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>

<div class="comments-section">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Necessitatibus repellendus, eos vitae perspiciatis maxime cupiditate a dicta numquam quibusdam saepe, ullam fugit fugiat atque. Fugiat quam voluptatibus mollitia, cupiditate in.
</div>
<!-- Bootstrap Core Javascript -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js"></script>
<script src="assets/js/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="assets/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="assets/js/main.js"></script>

</html>
```

CSS:

```
.panel {
    border-radius: 0 !important;
    border: none;
    -webkit-box-shadow: none;
    box-shadow: none;
    height: 45px;
}
.panel-default > .panel-heading {
    color: black;
    background-color: white;
    border-radius: 0;
    height: 45px;
    padding: 0;
}
.panel-title {
    font-size: 18px;
    vertical-align: middle;
    line-height: 45px;
    font-family: futura-pt, sans-serif;
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: 500;
}
.panel-title a {
    text-decoration: none;
}
.panel-title .ion-chevron-down {
    padding: 0 16px 0 16px;
}
.panel-title .ion-chevron-up {
    padding: 0 16px 0 16px;
}
.panel-body{
    background-color: white;
    font-size: 14px;  
    margin-bottom: 66px;
}
```

**Before clicking the dropdown**
[image: Before clicking the dropdown]

**After clicking dropdown**
[image: AFter]

Answer (score 1):

- Do you need this?

```css
.panel {
    border-radius: 0 !important;
    border: none;
    -webkit-box-shadow: none;
    box-shadow: none;
}
```

```css
.panel {
    border-radius: 0 !important;
    border: none;
    -webkit-box-shadow: none;
    box-shadow: none;
}
.panel-default > .panel-heading {
    color: black;
    background-color: white;
    border-radius: 0;
    height: 45px;
    padding: 0;
}
.panel-title {
    font-size: 18px;
    vertical-align: middle;
    line-height: 45px;
    font-family: futura-pt, sans-serif;
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: 500;
}
.panel-title a {
    text-decoration: none;
}
.panel-title .ion-chevron-down {
    padding: 0 16px 0 16px;
}
.panel-title .ion-chevron-up {
    padding: 0 16px 0 16px;
}
.panel-body{
    background-color: white;
    font-size: 14px;  
    margin-bottom: 66px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <meta name="description" content="" />
    <meta name="author" content="" />
    <link rel="icon" href="assets/img/favicon.ico" />

    <title>UNCVRD</title>

    <!-- Bootstrap Core CSS -->
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

    <!-- Font awesome icons -->
    <link href="assets/css/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

    <!-- Custom Css -->
    <link href="assets/css/custom.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Google Fonts -->
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Reem+Kufi" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="https://use.typekit.net/wvu7wqs.js"></script>
    <script>
        try {
            Typekit.load({
                async: true
            });
        } catch (e) {}

    </script>

    <!-- Ionicons -->
    <link href="http://code.ionicframework.com/ionicons/2.0.1/css/ionicons.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- HTML5 shiv and REspond.js IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->

    <!--[if lt IE9]>
    <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.2/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->

</head>


<div class="lyrics-container">
    <div class="panel-group">
        <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-heading">
                <h4 class="panel-title">
                              <a data-toggle="collapse" id="lyric-toggle" href="#collapse1"><i class="icon ion-chevron-down"></i>LYRICS</a>
                            </h4>
            </div>
            <div id="collapse1" class="panel-collapse collapse">
                <div class="panel-body">
                    Don't tell me this is over
                    <br> I'll carry you on my shoulder
                    <br> I'm marching on like a soldier
                    <br> Turn up the heat
                    <br> I get colder
                    <br> You see the trash as a treasure
                    <br> I'm getting closer than ever
                    <br> But there it blow,
                    <br> I got stronger
                    <br> Just need a little bit longer
                    <br> I'm the one but a sinner
                    <br> I'm finding to see it clearer
                    <br> So let me show you the winner
                    <br> That's how I pray for forgiveness
                    <br> No I ain't drowning, I'm boiling
                    <br> I'll left this world up alone
                    <br> I'll never be a quitter
                    <br> Even if it would kill me
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>

<div class="comments-section">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Necessitatibus repellendus, eos vitae perspiciatis maxime cupiditate a dicta numquam quibusdam saepe, ullam fugit fugiat atque. Fugiat quam voluptatibus mollitia, cupiditate in.
</div>
<!-- Bootstrap Core Javascript -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js"></script>
<script src="assets/js/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="assets/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="assets/js/main.js"></script>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not completely sure what you are asking for however i would recommend either sending it to another page i.e a simple go to a page

```
    <li>
    <a href="testemonials.html">Testemonials</a>
    </li>
```

If you add this to your navbar clicking on it will redirect. However if you want it to actually just dropdown you would have to have a downloaded copy on the bootstrap css and change the @media width for the small screen size to one of a bigger length and get rid of the conflicting media widths. This should mean that it will stick at that at any width. I hope this helps. To see what i mean decrease your window width to really small and it will hit a break point at which the navbar method should change.

Comment: I do not want to jump to a new page, I have a dropdown menu halfway down the page (called Lyrics) that I want to dropdown to reveal the lyrics. Right now, if I place text beneath the dropdown, the text appears above the dropdown interfering with the text inside the dropdown. Open this page as mobile: http://genius.com/Rae-sremmurd-black-beatles-lyrics scroll down to the "Ask Questions" section where it features a similar drop down feature. Does what I want to accomplish make sense? I removed most code in the above to make it less cluttered

Answer (score 0):

Try `class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"` instead of `data-toggle="collapse"`, might work

Answer (score 0):

```css
.panel {
    border-radius: 0 !important;
    border: none;
    -webkit-box-shadow: none;
    box-shadow: none;
}
```

- delete height: 45px of class penel

Comment: this didnt fix anything

Comment: or it is not match what you need?